# How to swap table names in cast that both tables already created?

Tags: mysql

Let's suppose that we have two tables `new` and `current` (both are innodb).
We should atomically truncate `current` table contents and fill with new content from `new` table.

Possible ways:

- swap table names `RENAME TABLE`, but it can't help because both tables are already created
- start transaction; truncate `current` table; insert into `current` select from `new`; commit transaction - it is ok, but is it possible to make all this actions in transcational way?
- create on fly third table and use it like a bridge

What is the best practice?

UPD: I suppose this will work perfectly: `RENAME TABLE current TO xxx, new TO current; xxx TO new`

Comment: What is the reason for having two tables in the first place? - Also how much data are you talking about here?

Comment: @Steve, not too much data. About 50-100K rows of 5-10 int fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rename current to temp and then new to current and last create table new one and drop temp table

Comment: `RENAME TABLE current TO xxx, new TO current; xxx TO new` this way, right?

Comment: You want to truncate  current right then simply create  new table again and drop temp

Comment: RENAME TABLE current TO xxx, new TO current; Create table new ;drop temp

Answer (score 6):

You'll need to rename the tables using a single MySQL statement so it's performed as a single mysql atomic operation, else you can cause errors for programs trying to access one of the tables while swapping them between the various names.

But it also sounds like you need the "new" table to be empty to accept new records at the end of the operation.

```
CREATE TABLE new_empty LIKE new;
RENAME TABLE current TO old, new to current, new_empty TO new;
DROP TABLE old;
```

This is much more efficient than doing a "truncate current" and an "insert into current select * from new" because you don't copy any records, it only creates a new table structure (with its indexes), renames three files and drops the old table (by deleting the two files from the database directory).

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/rename-table.html

Answer (score -4):

First, You will need to make sure that the current table should not be locked.

If we have two table **table1** and **table2**

```
RENAME TABLE table1 TO table1_temp;
RENAME TABLE table2 TO table1;
RENAME TABLE table1_temp TO table2;
```

Try this. This will definatly help you.

Comment: This will NOT be atomic. So, after the first rename, there is no table1. Your application will start to fail. After the second rename, there is no table2. More issues.

Comment: I think you should try, This will work. I write this after running these queries in MYSQL 5.6 and it's so simple. So, please at least try at once before rating any comment.